# NoSuchField error in Java code with two classes

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class Table {

Table2[] data = new Table2[2000];
public Table() {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = new Table2();
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Table2 {

   Integer[] data;

   public Table2() {
       data = new Integer[100];
   }
```

Im having problems accessing `Table.data[0].data[0]`

```
Table.data[0].data[0] is not null.
```

The program works in Eclipse but outside of Eclipse i get a NoSuchField error. Im not sure how to fix this.

Comment: I don't think `Table.data.data` exists based on results from my compiler.

Comment: I have a piece of code that inserts an integer into Table.data[0].data[0]. I cant post the entire code here because of plagiarism reasons.

Comment: An exception message with no stack trace doesn't really give us enough to work with, especially when the access issue describes a non-static object in a static context.

Comment: This is not a 
[minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your error message. This **is not** the code you are running. Show us a full stack trace **with pointers to the line that causes the error as we cannot see line numbers in stack overflow** to give us a proper example to work with.

Comment: Who upvoted this question? It is not useful and very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You must be doing some typo/mistake in your code accessing it. If you do it as follows, no matter where (eclipse or outside) you are accessing it, the result will be same.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Table table=new Table();
        table.data[0].data[0]=10;
        System.out.println(table.data[0].data[0]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10
```